# Is this a bug in Etherscan

Tags: transactions, etherscan

[This transaction](https://etherscan.io/tx/0xf0a136e31c17a26eb45512b0a24fb987367aa86f9e1aae26754b3cb699b6a89d) shows that account `0x152ae79400fdeee287849f35e4f687316e27bae6` sent this smart contract `0x14fbca95be7e99c15cc2996c6c9d841e54b79425` a transaction that interally invoked the maker token contract and that as part of that invocation, [this event](https://etherscan.io/tx/0xf0a136e31c17a26eb45512b0a24fb987367aa86f9e1aae26754b3cb699b6a89d#eventlog) was created (the third one).

Question: When I look at the maker token contract's list of transactions [0x9f8f72aa9304c8b593d555f12ef6589cc3a579a2](https://etherscan.io/address/0x9f8f72aa9304c8b593d555f12ef6589cc3a579a2), I think I should find block 4978662 included in the account's internal transactions list, but it isn't.

Am I missing something? Is this a bug in Etherscan?